# SOAP Query Error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, xquery

I want to use SOAP and xQuery to query an XML file on a local exist database, but I get the following error in the browser:

Functions:

array(10) { [0]=> string(56) "getResourceResponse getResource(getResource $parameters)" [1]=> string(38) "queryResponse query(query $parameters)" [2]=> string(44) "connectResponse connect(connect $parameters)" [3]=> string(47) "retrieveResponse retrieve(retrieve $parameters)" [4]=> string(53) "disconnectResponse disconnect(disconnect $parameters)" [5]=> string(68) "getResourceDataResponse getResourceData(getResourceData $parameters)" [6]=> string(41) "xqueryResponse xquery(xquery $parameters)" [7]=> string(59) "retrieveDataResponse retrieveData(retrieveData $parameters)" [8]=> string(77) "retrieveByDocumentResponse retrieveByDocument(retrieveByDocument $parameters)" [9]=> string(65) "listCollectionResponse listCollection(listCollection $parameters)" }

SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] java.lang.NullPointerException in C:\xampp\htdocs\phexist\helloclient.php:8 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('xquery', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\phexist\helloclient.php(8): SoapClient->xquery('Ross') #2 {main}

Server Code:

```
<?php 
include ('include/eXist.php');
function xquery($firstName) { 
return "Hello ".$firstName; 
//sayhello

 try
{
$db = new eXist();
# Connect
$db->connect() or die ($db->getError());

$query = 'for $line in //Orders/Taxes return $line';

print "<p><b>XQuery:</b></p><pre>$query</pre>";

# XQuery execution
//$db->setDebug(TRUE);
$db->setHighlight(FALSE);
$result = $db->xquery($query) or die ($db->getError());
}



 ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache 
 $server = new SoapServer("http://localhost:8080/exist/services/Query?wsdl"); 
$server->addFunction("xquery"); 
$server->handle(); 
 ?>
```

Client Code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/exist/services /Query?wsdl");
echo "Functions:<br/><br/>";
echo var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
echo "<br/><br/>";
try
{
$return = $client->xquery("Ross");
echo($return."<br>");
}
catch(SoapFault $soapFault)
{
echo ($soapFault);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the result of 'sayhello' rather than the xquery. Distributed Computing module??

Comment: Yes, do you know how I can get it working? I'm not very good at this as you can see.

Comment: I'm also doing that module haha, USW??

Comment: Yeah haha, I haven't got a clue how to make it work.

Comment: Well I was doing something very similar to you but mine also doesn't work. The only advice I can give is look at your server code, you've got the sayhello function mixed with the 'xquery' one.